# Set Theory Jech - Induction Proof Ex. 1.9

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Exercise 1.9 in Set Theory (Jech) asks : Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that  $\emptyset \in A$, and if $n \in A$ then $n + 1 \in A$. Then $A = \mathbb N$ .

I have seen some solutions using ∈-minimal property. But I proved it this way :

$\emptyset \in A$

Also, if $n \in A$, $n+1 \in A$ i.e. $n \cup \{n\} \in A$

Hence $A$ is inductive => $\mathbb N$  is a subset of $A$ since $\mathbb N$  is the smallest inductive set.
But $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$  (by hypothesis).
Hence $A = \mathbb N$ .

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I guess, if you've defined $\mathbb N$ as the smallest inductive set you're right.